# Десериализация JSON в тип с абстрактным свойством

Tags: c#, json, json.net

У меня есть класс с абстрактным свойством:

```
class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("person-type")]
    public string PersonType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("person-value")]
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}

abstract class Person { }

class Employee : Person
{
    public string A { get; set; }
}

class Manager : Person
{
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

Мне нужно десериализовать эту структуру из JSON. Проблема в том, что JSON не понимает, как ему десериализовать структуру в абстрактный тип. Как решить эту проблему?

UPD

1. Свойство `PersonType` может принимать значения "Employee" или "Manager".
2. Для десериализации использую метод `JsonSerializer.Deserialize`.
3. Насколько я понимаю, мне нужно реализовать конвертер для типа `Foo`, но я не понимаю, как это правильно сделать.

UDP2

У меня нет доступа к JSON. Я получаю его из внешнего API. Соответственно, я могу получить

```
{
    "person-type": "Manager",
    "person-value": {
        "B": "some value"
    }
}
```

или

```
{
    "person-type": "Employee",
    "person-value": {
        "A": "some another value"
    }
}
```

Comment: Я тоже не понимаю, как десериализатор без посторонней помощи догадается сам выбрать нужный класс.

Comment: @tym32167, вопрос в том, какая помощь ему нужна и как ее оказать?

Comment: @Vlad передавать тип значения в json...

Comment: @tCode, добавил немного информации в вопрос. У меня нет доступа к структуре json.

Comment: Например,  написать [свой  конвертер](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20995865/312041)

Comment: @tym32167, проблема всех найденных мной примеров в том, что в наследниках есть свойство, которое определяет тип наследника. В моем случае такого свойства нет. Соответственно, мне нужен конвертер для типа `Foo`. При этом не хочется перекладывать все свойства вручную, а скопировать их в каком-нибудь цикле. Абстрактное свойство можно обработать отдельно. Примеров в таком виде мне не попадалось и самому не удалось сходу написать ничего подходящего.

Comment: Если вы сами, имея JObject и возможномть проверять в нем всё, что хочется, не можете разобраться сами как вам понять, какой класс использовать, то вам никакие конвертеры не помогут

Comment: @tym32167, можете разобраться - ответьте на вопрос. Не можете - проходите мимо. Ваш комментарий груб и не несет никакой полезной информации.

Comment: Вы меня неверно поняли. Я имею ввиду, что вам надо самому определиться, при каких условаиях в какой класс вам надо парсить. По ссылке, что я вам привел, есть точно решение точно такой же проблемы, что у вас, вам тлько осталось опеделить когда в какой класс надо сериализовать внктри корвертера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге пришел к такому решению. Оно годится в моем случае, но, возможно, не сработает в каких-нибудь более изощренных ситуациях.

Создаем базовый конвертер для типа, который может содержать свойства абстрактного типа. Этот конвертер будет копировать все свойства в JObject в созданный объект класса T. Если конвертеру попадается свойство абстрактного типа, то он вызывает абстрактный метод `GetAbstractPropertyValue`, в который передает всю информацию о текущем объекте и свойстве.

Дополнительно добавил словарик, который будет кэшировать мэппинг наименования json-свойства на информацию о свойстве объекта.

```
internal abstract class AbstractPropertyContainerJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
    where T : new()
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, PropertyInfo> properties;

    static AbstractPropertyContainerJsonConverter()
    {
        properties = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();
    }

    public sealed override bool CanWrite => false;

    public sealed override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, [AllowNull] T value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public sealed override T ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, [AllowNull] T existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return default;
        }

        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        var result = hasExistingValue ? existingValue : new T();

        foreach (var jProperty in jObject.Properties())
        {
            var propertyInfo = properties.GetOrAdd(jProperty.Name, GetPropertyInfoOrDefault);

            if (propertyInfo != null)
            {
                var value = propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsAbstract ?
                    GetAbstractPropertyValue(jObject, jProperty, propertyInfo) :
                    jProperty.Value.ToObject(propertyInfo.PropertyType);

                propertyInfo.SetValue(result, value);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected abstract object GetAbstractPropertyValue(JObject jObject, JProperty jProperty, PropertyInfo propertyInfo);

    private PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfoOrDefault(string jsonPropertyName)
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty);

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            // сначала поищем свойство по атрибуту
            var jsonPropertyAttribute = property.GetCustomAttributes<JsonPropertyAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (jsonPropertyAttribute?.PropertyName.Equals(jsonPropertyName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                return property;
            }

            // потом по имени
            if (property.Name.Equals(jsonPropertyName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return property;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Далее нужно добавить наследника для конкретного типа. В нашем случае - типа `Foo`:

```
internal sealed class FooJsonConverter : AbstractPropertyContainerJsonConverter<Foo>
{
    protected override object GetAbstractPropertyValue(JObject jObject, JProperty jProperty, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        var typeName = jObject.Property("person-type").Value.ToObject<string>();

        switch (typeName)
        {
            case "Employee":
                return jProperty.Value.ToObject<Employee>();
            case "Manager":
                return jProperty.Value.ToObject<Manager>();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Осталось прилепить конвертер к классу `Foo`:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(FooJsonConverter))]
class Foo { ... }
```

Использование:

```
var foo = new Foo
{
    PersonType = "Manager",
    Person = new Manager
    {
        B = "bb"
    }
};

// работает стандартный конвертер
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);

// работает наш конвертер
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

С данной проблемой уже сталкивались - [гит .net core 3](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/39903). Решается она созданием класса-конвертера:

```
private class PersonPolymorphicSerializerConverter : JsonConverter<Person>
{
    public override Person Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException($"Deserializing not supported. Type={typeToConvert}.");
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Person value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, value.GetType(), options);
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new PersonPolymorphicSerializerConverter());
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(person, options);
```

[Полный пример](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/fbb8b5c4b9566ba81596aa35f42b71bbda601528/src/System.Text.Json/tests/Serialization/CustomConverterTests.Polymorphic.cs#L159-L218) решения

UPD: Десериализация (костыль?)

```
private class FooConverter: JsonConverter<Foo>
{
    public override Foo Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        reader.Read();
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        string propertyName = reader.GetString();
        if (propertyName != "person-type")
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        reader.Read();
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        Foo value;
        string PersonType = (string)reader.GetString();
        value.Person = GetPerson(PersonType, reader);

        reader.Read();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
        {
            return value;
        }

        throw new JsonException();
    }

    private static Person GetPerson(string type, ref Utf8JsonReader reader)
    {
        Person result;
        switch(type)
        {
            case "Employee":
                result = new Employee();
                break;
            case "Manager":
                result = new Manager();
                break;
        }
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
            {
                throw new JsonException();
            }
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                break;
            }           
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                string prop_name = reader.GetString();//token_prop_name
                var prop_info = result.GetType().GetProperty(prop_name);
                reader.Read();
                string prop_value = reader.GetString();//token_prop_value
                if(prop_info != null)
                    prop_info.SetValue(result, prop_value, null);
            }               
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Как раз с сериализацией проблем нет. json нормально конвертирует наследника абстрактного класса. Вопрос в десериализации.

Comment: @Vlad в public override Person Read() обработать typeToConvert?

Comment: В моем случае там будет тип `Person`, разве нет? Чем мне эта информация поможет? Как в методе `Read` достучаться до свойства `PersonType` класса `Foo`?

Comment: @Vlad обновил ответ, не могу затестить на .net core 3.0 - прямиком из блокнота

Comment: Спасибо. Вернусь к этой задаче - проверю.

Comment: Я использую Newtonsoft.Json. Ваш вариант предназначен для какого-то сериализатора из .net core? Не уверен, что они взаимозаменяемы. В общем, написал свой вариант. В любом случае, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Vlad не за что) да, JsonSerializer есть в system.text.json в .net core 3.0, а ваш тэг "json.net" упустил попросту :(

Answer (score 0):

Для абстрактного поля нужно добавить свойство type, например, если животное утка:

```
{
    "animal": {
        "type": "duck-type",
        "quacks": true,
    }
}
```

А если животное собака:

```
{
    "animal": {
        "type": "dog-type",
        "barks": true,
    }
}
```

Давным-давно делал реализацию для Newtonsoft.Json, корявенькая, но работает.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

using AutoMapper;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace CyberServer.Additional
{
    public class TypedByProperty<T> where T : TypedByProperty<T>
    {
        public static IDictionary<string, Type> Types{get=>throw new NotImplementedException("Метод требуется переопределить, используя оператор new!");}
        public static void AddChild(KeyValuePair<string, Type> child){new NotImplementedException("Метод требуется переопределить, используя оператор new!");}

        protected virtual IDictionary<string, Type> StaticTypes{get;}

        public Type[] GetTypesArray()
        {
            return StaticTypes.Select(t => t.Value).ToArray();
        }

        public Type GetCurrentType(string v)
        {
            return StaticTypes[v];
        }

        public object GetCurrentInstance(JToken token)
        {
            try
            {
                Type type = GetCurrentType(token["type"].ToString());
                return token.ToObject(type);
            }
            catch (JsonSerializationException)
            {
                return null;
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        string type = string.Empty;

        [JsonProperty("type")]
        [BsonElement("type")]
        public string Type
        {
            get
            {
                if (type == string.Empty)
                {
                    throw new ClientStateException("type-empty");
                }
                return type;
            }
            set
            {
                type = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public class TypedByPropertyConverter<T> : JsonConverter where T:TypedByProperty<T>, new()
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType==typeof(T);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
            TypedByProperty<T> obj = new T();
            try
            {
                return obj.GetCurrentInstance(token);
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Пример класса Animal:

```
public class Animal : TypedByProperty<Animal>
{      
    /* Сопоставление значения type к типу хранится в приватном статичном поле */
    static readonly new IDictionary<string,Type> Types = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    /* Для получения типа конвертором */
    protected override IDictionary<string,Type> StaticTypes{get=>Types;}
    /* Для добавления типа со стороны */
    public static new void AddChild(KeyValuePair<string,Type> child){Types.Add(child);}
}
```

Использование:

```
[JsonProperty("actualCompetition")]    
[JsonConverter(typeof(TypedByPropertyConverter<Animal>))]
public Animal Animal{get;set;}
```

Comment: Я не могу поменять структуру этих типов. Я получаю JSON из API, к которому у меня нет доступа.

Comment: @Vlad press F to pay respect. А если серьезно, то задача решается написанием конвертора, который ориентируется на текущие поля объекта

Comment: Да, но хотелось бы скопировать все текущие поля в каком-нибудь цикле по jProperty, а значение этого поля выбрать вручную.

Comment: @Vlad В данном примере возможные типы добавляются динамично, а так, у C# все совсем неоднозначно с динамичными объектами
https://lintaonz.wordpress.com/2014/04/10/memory-leak-of-expandoobject-in-c/

Comment: Возможные типы наследников? Их количество ограничено и их перечень известен на этапе компиляции. Незнакомый тип можно устанавливать в null, или бросать исключение.